# How to obtain clock signal from crystal oscillator?

Tags: oscillator

I got myself a 3.579545 MHz quartz oscillator. However, I would like to use it as clock source for another chip (for example the YM3812 needs this clock rate). 
The piece has just two pins. How do I connect them with voltage source, to obtain clock signal of this specific frequency?

Comment: If it has only two pins it's not an oscillator, probably a crystal for the North American color burst frequency used in the NTSC television sets of days of yore.

Comment: Is it a quartz **crystal** or an **oscillator**? If it has just two pins then it is probably a bare crystal. Please provide a part number and a link to the datasheets for the crystal and the chip you want to use it with.

Comment: Or a photo. . .

Answer (score 1):

It is not a quartz oscillator, it is a quartz crystal, which needs to be connected to an oscillator circuit to make a clock signal. Many crystal datasheets and application notes have a diagram how to build it with unbuffered CMOS inverters, such as 74HCU04 or CD4069. I would not build it from a 74LS04, but with some fine tuning it generated good enough clock for YM3812. However, it does not specifically need this rate, but it is a common clock for it in many systems (e.g. in PCs).

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of crystals, both which resonate in series and the parallel mode not far apart in values of freq. to be concerned for audio.

This shows what they used in series mode with two inverting stages used for this in feedback.
[image]
[ref](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/ym3812-ym3012-issue/)